# ASSIMP skeletal animation with some FBX files has issues - weird node added

Tags: skeletal-animation, fbx, assimp

Hi I'm trying to work load fbx files to my OpenGL Renderer using ASSIMP.

However, weird nodes that are not in the original fbx file are added whenever I load the file with the ASSIMP importer.

For example, this is part of the node hierarchy printed while loading the nodes in a DFS matter.

```
mixamorig:LeftForeArm_$AssimpFbx$_Translation
ㄴmixamorig:LeftForeArm_$AssimpFbx$_PreRotation
 ㄴmixamorig:LeftForeArm_$AssimpFbx$_Rotation
  ㄴmixamorig:LeftForeArm_$AssimpFbx$_Scaling
   ㄴmixamorig:LeftForeArm
```

However, according to the original file, there should only be `mixamorig:LeftForeArm`.

This fbx file might be weird since usually in the case of other fbx files, I can get the node's translation, rotation, scaling keyframes directly from aiNodeAnim using the node's name. I never saw a case where the keyframe itself become a node.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Assimp::Importer importer;
// add the next code,you'll get a sigle node
importer.SetPropertyBool(AI_CONFIG_IMPORT_FBX_PRESERVE_PIVOTS, false);

Comment: Enabling this property breaks animations. This is a known issue with Assimp that still has not been fixed.